# expand pandas groupby results to initial dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have a dataframe `df` and group it by a few columns, `dfg`, with the median of one of its columns. How could I then take those median values, and expand them out so that those mean values are in a new column of the original `df`, and associated with the respective conditions? This will mean there are duplicates, but I will next be using this column for a subsequent calculation and having these in a column will make this possible.

Example data:

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'idx':[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2],
        'condition1':[1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4],
        'condition2':[1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2],
        'values':np.random.normal(0,1,16)}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

dfg = df.groupby(['idx', 'condition2'], as_index=False)['values'].median()
```

example of desired result (note duplicates corresponding to correct conditions):

```
    idx condition1  condition2  values  medians
0   1   1   1   0.35031 0.656355
1   1   1   2   -0.291736   -0.024304
2   1   2   1   1.593545    0.656355
3   1   2   2   -1.275154   -0.024304
4   1   3   1   0.075259    0.656355
5   1   3   2   1.054481    -0.024304
6   1   4   1   0.9624  0.656355
7   1   4   2   0.243128    -0.024304
8   2   1   1   1.717391    1.155406
9   2   1   2   0.788847    1.006583
10  2   2   1   1.145891    1.155406
11  2   2   2   -0.492063   1.006583
12  2   3   1   -0.157029   1.155406
13  2   3   2   1.224319    1.006583
14  2   4   1   1.164921    1.155406
15  2   4   2   2.042239    1.006583
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with `median` for new column:

```
df['medians'] = df.groupby(['idx', 'condition2'])['values'].transform('median')
```

Comment: Nice, thanks for the solution. I've just looked at the page for the transform function but I'm still not clear how it works, particularly in this case. Could you explain it to me please?

Comment: @fffrost - Sure, it is really similar like aggregation, like `df.groupby(['idx', 'condition2'], as_index=False)['values'].median()`. There is only one difference - output is same length like original DataFrame, so repeated aggregation values. Because same length, is possible add  new column to original dataFrame